# Shunting yard (Reverse Polish Notation/Postfix) operator precedence

Tags: operators, evaluation, operator-precedence, postfix-mta, shunting-yard

I'm trying to figure out what the precedence is for the different operators when implementing the shuting yard algorithm.

My abstract syntax tree is in infix and I'm evaluating using the shuting yard algorithm. This works just fine for the arithmetic operators. The issue I'm facing is that I don't know what precedence all the other operators has.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm I can see that the following is true for these operators. The number is the precedence.

```
^   4   
*   3 
/   3
+   2
−   2
```

But I cannot seem to find anything that describes the precedense for the relational and logical operators? I've searched alot for an answer.

Can somebody give me the complete picture of the precedense for all of these operators:

```
a. Function call
b. (
c. ,
d. +, -
e. *, /
f. ^
g. =, <>, <, <=, >, >=
h. NOT
i. AND
j. OR
```

Thanks in advance.

/Brian

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Mathematica [Operator Input Forms](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) which shows the operator input forms, in order of decreasing precedence. Operators of equal precedence are grouped together.

You can determine the "precedence" like this in Mathematica:

```
Precedence[Power] gives 590
Precedence[Times] gives 400
Precedence[Plus] gives 310
Precedence[Equal] gives 290
Precedence[Not] gives 230
Precedence[And] gives 215
Precedence[Or] gives 215
```